# ASP.NET Core 2.1 CreatedAtRoute Returns no Response

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.1

I was searching around but I couldn't find a working answer for my issue. I saw a similar question but we had different results. My issue is I have 2 controllers. The first controller has a POST action that I want to return a `CreatedAtRoute` to a GET action inside a different controller. I tested the GET action in Postman and it works so my only issue is getting the `CreatedAtRoute` to work.

My first controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Submit(AssessmentAttemptVM attempt)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    //Do database related stuff
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return CreatedAtRoute("GetAssessmentResult", new { id = studentAttempt.Id }, studentAttempt);
}
```

My second controller:

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetAssessmentResult")]
public async Task<ActionResult<AssessmentResultVM>> GetById(int id)
{
    //Get my ViewModel -- This works if I try to access it without using the CreatedAtRoute method
    return resultVM;
}
```

The picture below shows what Postman responds with when I try to Post. I verified that the data gets added to the database so only the `CreatedAtRoute` method is the only I can think of that isn't making this work for me..
[image: This is what Postman shows me when I try to post.]

**EDIT**

Controller Route Attributes:

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("api/view/assessmentresult/")]
    public class AssessmentResultsController: ControllerBase
    {

[ApiController]
    [Route("api/take/assessment")]
    public class StudentAssessmentController : ControllerBase
    {
```

Comment: Try using `CreatedAtAction` ie: `return CreatedAtAction("GetById", "SecondController",new { id = studentAttempt.Id }, studentAttempt);` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Nkosi I tried that just now, and it didn't sadly..

Comment: Then something else is blocking the response from the first controller. What you had originally should have worked.

Comment: Could you give us your route attributes on the controller? Also what happens when you specify the HttpPost attribute with an empty string, that is, `[HttpPost("")]`

Comment: @DaveAgaba I added my route on my question. Nothing changed after adding the (""). I placed that on Submit btw if I understood you right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause. The last parameter for `CreatedAtRoute` and `CreatedAtAction` required an object similar to the destination controller. It went over my head because I was sending models prior to what I did now which used a ViewModel.

*Well* That wasn't the main reason I couldn't get a response though. It was because of an execption where the object I'm passing ended up having recursive references because I was sending a model that wasn't properly formatted to be sent over as JSON.

I used this to make it work, taken from the MS Docs site:
`CreatedAtAction(String, String, Object, Object)` Where the last parameter should be the object you want to the api to send over.

PS: I also didn't notice immediately because when I debugged the project, it didn't crash and had to read the logs. I'm a noob so I really didn't know that it's possible for an exception to occur without the project crashing in debug mode.